# ShareKit Facebook Error After Integration... Not able to post the message

Tags: ios, sharekit

I have been able to integrate the Facebook API using Sharekit.
But currently i am being displayed with the following error.
Can someone provide a lead to me on this that what is going wrong here.
The screen shot for the error is displayed below:

[image: Facebook Error]

Comment: Do you use [original ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com), or [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)?

Comment: I have used the new version i.e. ShareKit 2.0

Comment: You might try to enable ShareKit debug mode in DefaultSHKConfigurator.h. Then you should see the actual requests and responses from services. This might help you to find what is going on.

Comment: It didnt work still stuck at the same problem

Comment: it looks like wrong credentials for your app. Can you double check appid etc? If in doubt, you can look at how it is done in the demo app.

Comment: one more [hint](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues/434#issuecomment-6680747)

Answer (score 1):

Enter the Facebook APIID in SHKConfig.h file